Blazor server as windows service not create sqlite3 database
I created a Blazor server application that, among other things, reads and records data in the sql3 database. The application works normally in visual studio, but when I host the application as a windows service, the application does not create a sqlite database on the local disk.
my appsettings:
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "MonitorDb": "Data Source=monitor.db"
    },
        "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        },
        "EventLog": {
            "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information"
            }
        }
    },
    "DetailedErrors": true,
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "Kestrel": {
        "Endpoints": {
            "Http": {
            "Url": "http://localhost:5100"
            }
        }
    }
}

DbContext class:
    public class ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : 

DbContext(options)
{
    public DbSet<ConfigurationModel> Configurations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ConfigurationModel>().HasData(
            new ConfigurationModel
            {
                Id = 1,
                ClientKey = "1",
                HubAddress = "http://localhost",
                HubPort = "5100",
                HubName = "monitorhub"
            }
        );
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
}

part of the Programs.cs code that creates the base if it doesn't exist:
// create database if not exists
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
}


Have you tried changing the config to create the database file in a different location? It is possibly a permissions problem - the account running the service perhaps does not have permission to create the file

Thanks Mister Magoo, this helped. Now it works
